# How to check for a new entry in postgres through python?

Tags: python, postgresql

How to check for new entry in postgres with sqlalchemy? What will the possible logic be using timestamp or primary id?

Comment: *Through Python* - is a vague term. What are you using postgres with ? Is it any framework ? Post your complete use-case.

Comment: @Ram postgres with sqlalchemy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Possible logic could be:

```
from time import sleep
import pyodbc
import pandas as pd

While True:            
   conn_sql = pyodbc.connect('DSN=YOUR_DSN; UID=YOUR_USER; PWD=YOUR_PASSWORD')
   # get actual records count         
   actual_records_count = pd.read_sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.your_table", conn_sql)
   # wait 5 seconds    
   sleep(5)
   # get "new" actual records count 
   new_records_count  = pd.read_sql("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM dbo.your_table", conn_sql)
            
   If actual_records_count == new_records_count:
      print("There's no new records here")
   else:
      print("New row added")
```

**DISCLAIMER** :`while True` means loop forever. The while statement takes an expression and executes the loop body while the expression evaluates to (boolean) `"true"`. True always evaluates to boolean `"true"` and thus executes the loop body indefinitely.